# What's the syntax error here?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, psql

(Using postgresql 9.1)

I have a view and I'm trying to remove the row corresponding to the maximum values to find the second highest value. I want to store this new relation in another view.

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView AS

    SomeOtherView

    EXCEPT

    (SELECT *
    FROM SomeOtherView
    WHERE attribute = (SELECT max(attribute) FROM SomeOtherView));
```

It keeps telling me there's a syntax error around the first "SomeOtherView" but I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: I don't think this is valid syntax. You need a result set to `EXCEPT` from.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `SomeOtherView` with

```
 SELECT * FROM SomeOtherView
```